# How can I change `fs.notify.max_user_watches` on Azure Container Instances?

Tags: azure, containers

I'm deploying an application called [Theia](https://theia-ide.org) (a cloud-based IDE) on Azure Container Instances. The app is throwing errors about not being able to watch project files for changes. I did some research and this happens when `fs.notify.max_user_watches` is too low. I checked on the container instance, and apparently it's set to the default of `8192`.

I tried running `sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288`, but I get an error saying that `/sys` is mounted read-only.

Is there any other way for me to change this setting in ACI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working w/ Azure support on this, they said it wasn't currently supported. However, they have notified the ACI team of the feature request.